# Why do my threads stop?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, urllib2

I have a `list` consisting of ID's, about 50k per day.

and i have to make 50k request per day to the server { the server is at the same city } , and fetch the information and store it into database ... i've done that using `loop` and `Threads`
and i've notice that after unknown period of time it's stop fetching and storing ...

take a look of my code fragment

```
import re,urllib,urllib2
import mysql.connector as sql
import threading
from time import sleep
import idvalid

conn = sql.connect(user="example",password="example",host="127.0.0.1",database="students",collation="cp1256_general_ci")
cmds = conn.cursor()

ids=[] #here is going to be stored the ID's

def fetch():
    while len(ids)>0:#it will loop until the list of ID's is finish 
        try:
            idnumber = ids.pop()
            content = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/fetch.php?id="+idnumber,timeout=120).read()
            if content.find('<font color="red">') != -1:
                    pass
            else:
                    name=content[-20:]
                    cmds.execute("INSERT INTO `students`.`basic` (`id` ,`name`)VALUES ('%s', '%s');"%(idnumber,name))
        except Exception,r:
            print r,"==>",idnumber
            sleep(0.5)#i think sleep will help in threading ? i'm not sure
            pass
        print len(ids)#print how many ID's left

for i in range(0,50):#i've set 50 threads
    threading.Thread(target=fetch).start()
```

`output`:it will continue printing how many ID's left and at unknown moment it stops printing and fetching & storing

Comment: `mysql.connector` defines a [`threadsafety`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety) of `1`, which means you shouldn't share the connection and cursors between threads without synchronisation.

Comment: just move the `sql.connect` and `conn.cursor()` inside the `fetch` function

Comment: @mpaolini - that's not really a good solution, creating a new database connection for each insert. It would be better to have just one thread doing the database inserts (maybe reading from a threading.Queue) while the others download and insert into the queue...

Comment: @mata no I was suggesting one connection per thread. Each connection will be used for multiple inserts. What you say is even better but seems a bit overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: yes i think so , because i'm going to modify it to about 350 threads,,,so i think if i move the sql connect , cursor  it will consume a lot of the computer resource

Comment: @mpaolini - mata solution is not overkill, it's just the right amount of kill.  Opening and closing DB connections is expensive, downloading HTTP is blocky and latency-ridden.  Queueing the data from many HTTP network threads to one DB update thread is a reasonable and efficient solution that should have good performance.

Comment: @MartinJames I was just proposing one open and one close connection per thread, (inside the `fetch` function but before the `while` loop) given that he had 50 threads, it didn't seem too bad. But even opening and closing a single connection for a single insert is not going to harm in a situation where, as you correctly pointed out, probably 90% of the time the wait will be in the socket call in `urlopen`. It really depends on how mission-critial is this code and how much time you have available for implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Both networking and threading are non-trivial... most probably the cause is a networking event that results in a hanging thread. I'd be interested to hear whether people have solutions for this, because I have suffered the same problem of threads that stop responding.

But there are some things I would definitely change in your code:

- I would never catch "Exception". Just catch those exceptions that you know how to deal with. If a network error occurs in one of your threads, you could retry rather than giving up on the id.
- There is a race condition in your code: you first check whether there is remaining content, and then you take it out. At the second point in time, the remaining work may have disappeared, resulting in an exception. If you find this difficult to fix, there is a brilliant python object that is meant to pass objects between threads without race conditions and deadlocks: the Queue object. Check it out.
- The "sleep(0.5)" is not helping threading in general. It should not be necessary. It may reduce the chance of hitting race conditions, but it is better to program race conditions totally out. On the other hand, having 50 threads at full spead banging the web server may not be a very friendly thing to do. Make sure to stay within the limits of what the service can offer.